# recursive dict comprehension

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am building out a complex dictionary with some unconventional code.  I'm just curious if there is some way to check the current dictionary's value or even the current list's values while building it out as to avoid duplicates/unwanted values.  Here is the code I have:

```
locations = {words[i]: map(lambda x: words[x::].index(words[i]) if words[i] in words[x::] and words[x::].index(words[i]) not in self[words[i]] else None, range(len(words))) for i in range(len(words))}

# the important part here is 

and words[x::].index(words[i]) not in self[words[i]]
```

Is anything like the above possible without for/while iteration?

Comment: You're correct when you said unconventional.  You really shouldn't use a comprehension for something this complex.  A `for` loop would be much clearer.

Comment: `import this`   --"readability counts."

Comment: For one thing, any time you're doing `for i in range(len(foo))` (whether in a comprehension or in a loop statement) just to access `foo[i]`, you're making this more complicated than you need; just use `for each_foo in foo` instead.

Comment: Also, our of curiosity, why did you use a `map` with a `lambda` instead of yet another comprehension?

Comment: Anyway, if you're looking for a way to see the current list's values to avoid duplicate values, that probably means you wanted a set (or maybe an OrderedSet) rather than a list in the first place…

Comment: If your code is wider than the code box, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @MattBryant, I am aware that a for loop would be clearer.  I was simply curious if there was some nice reference to the dictionary/list I was building during the comprehension to check its contents as it is building.

Comment: This was a poke around at a mock(way not even close to trying to be optimized) algorithm to do [deflating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE).  I should be considerate when bringing it on Stack, though.  Sorry dudes.  And thanks for the feedback as always.  All I wanted to know was whether or not I could reference self during a comp.  Got me answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I strongly doubt that you can access the list actually being built with a comprehension, as it doesn't exist so far.

Nevertheless, this doesn't mean that you cannot build a list removing duplicates in a functional manner. (Just keep in mind that python doesn't allow for TCO.)

If we want to build a list from another list, just using lists and not sets, ordered sets or the like, one way could be (half-way functional style):

```
def removeDuplicates (inList, acc):
    if not inList: return acc
    if inList [0] in acc: return removeDuplicates (inList [1:], acc)
    return removeDuplicates (inList [1:], acc + [inList [0] ] )
    #even tail-recursive, although this doesn't help in python

print (removeDuplicates ( [1,2,3,2,3,5,1], [] ) )
```

Works. So let's build a lambda-expression out of it:

```
rd = lambda inList, acc: acc if not inList else rd (inList [1:], acc + ( [] if inList [0] in acc else [inList [0] ] ) )

print (rd ( [1,2,3,2,3,5,1], [] ) )
```

Works, too. Now let's prepare this lambda for anonymity and recursion:

```
rd2 = lambda f, inList, acc: acc if not inList else f (f, inList [1:], acc + ( [] if inList [0] in acc else [inList [0] ] ) )

rec = lambda f, *a: f (f, *a)

print (rec (rd2, [1,2,3,2,3,5,1], [] ) )
```

Still works. Now let's remove the name for the lambdas and we got a recursive lambda that builds a list from another while removing duplicates (without `for` or other imperative loops):

```
print ( (lambda f, *a: f (f, *a) ) (lambda f, inList, acc: acc if not inList else f (f, inList [1:], acc + ( [] if inList [0] in acc else [inList [0] ] ) ), [1,2,3,2,3,5,1], [] ) )
```

Not exactly readable, but functional and recursive.

If you are into functional programming, `lambda f, *a: f (f, *a)` sure will be a close friend of yours.

inb4 `import this` and PEP8.